# Dynamic Chart in Php Using Chart.js

Tags: javascript, php, charts

i tried to draw dynamic chart using Chart.js but no output ... 
i follow this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mmz79gH0l6c&t=101s

and do every step in this video but NO OUTPUT So WHERE is The problem

data.php

```
<?php
header('Content-Type: application/json');
define('DB_HOST', '127.0.0.1');
define('DB_USERNAME', 'root');
define('DB_PASSWORD', '');
define('DB_NAME', 'test');
$mysqli = new mysqli(DB_HOST,DB_USERNAME,DB_PASSWORD,DB_NAME);
if(!$mysqli){
  die("Connection Failed: ".$mysqli->error);
}
$query = sprintf("SELECT playerid, score FROM score ORDER BY playerid");
$result = $mysqli->query($query);
$data = array();
foreach ($result as $row){
  $data[] = $row;
}
$result->close();
$mysqli->close();
print json_encode($data);
?>
```

bargraph.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Bargraph</title>
    <style type="text/css">
        #chart-container{
            width: 640px;
            height: auto;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="chart-container">
        <canvas id="mycanvas"></canvas>
    </div>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-3.2.1.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/Chart.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/app.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

app.js

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $.ajax({
        url: "http://localhost/chart/data.php",
        method: "GET",
        success: function(data) {
            console.log(data);
            var player = [];
            var score = [];

            for(var i in data){
                player.push("player " + data[i].playerid);
                score.push(data[i].score);
            }

            var chartdata = {
                labels: player,
                dataset : [
                    {
                        label: 'player score',
                        backgroundColor: 'rgba(200, 200, 200, 0.75)',
                        borderColor: 'rgba(200, 200, 200, 0.75)',
                        hoverBackgroundColor: 'rgba(200, 200, 200, 1)',
                        hoverBorderColor: 'rgba(200, 200, 200, 1)',
                        data: score
                    }
                ]
            };

            var ctx = $("#mycanvas");

            var barGraph = new Chart(ctx, {
                type: 'bar',
                data: chartdata
            });
        },
        error: function(data) {
            console.log(data);
        }
    });
});
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W7D2v.png)

Comment: Before you ask *where* the problem is, can you at least tell us *what* the problem is?

Comment: the problem is i followed the video in above but no output, just blank page

Comment: Open up the javascript console if you're using Chrome, it's in View > Developer > Javascript Console, and tell me if there's anything in red.

Comment: i found this

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'offsetWidth' of undefined
    at i (Chart.min.js:10)
    at new e (Chart.min.js:10)
    at Object.success (app.js:31)
    at j (jquery.min.js:2)
    at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (jquery.min.js:2)
    at x (jquery.min.js:4)
    at XMLHttpRequest.<anonymous> (jquery.min.js:4)

Comment: that is mean the error in library not in code ???

Comment: It means that you're passing the library an undefined value when it expects, well, a defined value. It sounds like your AJAX request to `data.php` is failing.

Comment: but the data in data.php is sent to bargraph.html and appear in console 
Array(5)
0
:
Object
1
:
Object
2
:
Object
3
:
Object
4
:
Object

Comment: Ok. The error says that you are making a call on line 31 of app.js that is causing the failure. What is on that line?

Comment: var barGraph = new Chart(ctx, {
    type: 'bar',
    data: chartdata
   });

Comment: Then either `ctx` or `chartdata` are undefined. Put a line that says only `debugger;` on line 30 and refresh the page with the Javascript Console open.

Comment: ok i will try again ... thanks :)

Comment: do you know any another tutorials to create charts ?

Comment: Nope, sorry! :(

Comment: no problem ... thanks at all